# Getting undefined value while submitting form through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form from the front end  that I am trying to submit to backend using ajax.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form_post">
  <input type="hidden" name="name" id="name" class="name" value="ABC">
  <input type="hidden" name="location"  id="location" class="location"  value="XYZ">
  <textarea class="c-textarea desc" name="desc"  id="desc" placeholder="Type your description"></textarea>
  <input type="file" id="file" class="file" name="file" >
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#form_post").submit(function() 
      {
        var formData = new FormData();
        $f2 = $('#file');
        formData.append('file', $f2.get(0).files[0]);
        formData.append('name', name.value);
        formData.append('location', location.value);
        formData.append('desc', desc.value);
       jQuery.ajax(
        {
          type: "POST",
          url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "class/send_data",
          data: formData,
          processData: false,
          contentType: false,
          success: function(res) 
            {
              alert(res);
              console.log(res);
            },
          error: function(errResponse) 
            {
              console.log(errResponse);
            }
        });
        return false;
      });  
</script>
```

In alert i am getting the value for desc but for name and location it is getting as undefined.

On backend i am fetching the values using following code

```
$data = array(
'name' = $this->input->post('name')
'location'->input->post('location')
'desc'->input->post('desc')
);
```

Can anyone please tell how i can fetch the values

Comment: access the variables from `$_POST` example: `$_POST['name'];`

Comment: request data in php doesn't get auto assigned to named variables

Comment: Fetch to where from where? Please be more specific on what are you trying to do
Fetch the values from UI and post them into backend?

Comment: I didn't notice the return false. Okay on the JQuery thing.

Comment: @Patrick Evans i don't think i understood your point, can you please elaborate and also i have updated my question, can you please go through it once again

Comment: @garmoncheg i have updated my post can you please have a look again

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, you need to access the values sent via ajax using `$_POST`

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$location = $_POST['location'];

echo $name.''.$location;        
?>
```

> EDIT

Change your `data` key in ajax call to

```
data: new FormData(this),
```

Comment: i am using this method to fetch the values, but it is not coming

Comment: i tried your way but i am getting blank answer now, also i have updated my post hope it gives a better idea